# Generating strings of words with space delimiters from cut statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, grep, cut

I am new to bash. When I run the following command:

```
grep "type" /root/myFile | cut-d'=' -f2
```

I get the following:

```
102
304
503
442
```

I want to store the contents of the first command into a variable such that the content of the variable would be the equivalent of declaring it like this:

```
myVariable="102 304 503 442"
```

I don't know how to go about this. Do I initialize `myVariable`with an empty string and traverse the content of the command line-by-line and append it into myVariable with white spaces in between or is there an easier way for doing this with bash?

Comment: If necessary, you could substitute the new lines for spaces by piping the output to `tr` like so: `tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myVariable=`grep "type" /root/myFile | cut-d'=' -f2`
```

What is between back-ticks (`) is run and the output is assigned to `myVariable`.

If your current output is separated by line feeds (`\n`), then you may want to replace them with spaces with `tr` such as:

```
myVariable=`grep "type" /root/myFile | cut-d'=' -f2`|tr '\n' ' '`
```

Note:  Some people prefer using the `$()` syntax instead of back-ticks but both are useful and when I have the choice I use the back-ticks.  The real advantage of having both is if you want to handle execution at two levels since the back-ticked expression will be sent to a sub-shell first and then the `$()` portion will be executed.

Comment: `$(...)` is easier on the eyes for command substitution. Easier to get the markup right with, too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `bash` itself, using command substitution and then parameter expansion.

First take the output of the command in a variable by using command substitution `$()`, and then use parameter expansion to replace all newlines with spaces `${variable//$'\n'/ }`:

```
$ myVariable=$(grep "type" /root/myFile | cut-d'=' -f2) 
$ myVariable=${myVariable//$'\n'/ }
$ echo $myVariable
102 304 503 442
```

But for re-usability and cleanliness, you would be better off using an array:

```
myArray=( $(grep "type" /root/myFile | cut-d'=' -f2) )
```

and iterate over the array elements in the usual manner.